# When do I get to upgrade my ship?

Tags: starbound

**When do I get to upgrade my ship? And how?**, *without using the `/spawnitem shipT#` command?*
Replace the '#' with a Tier number (1 to 10?).

... Or using the `/upgradeship` command.

---

So, now that Starbound has been released into 1.0, I've noticed that several of the mechanics and methods to do things have been overhauled. For one, spamming daggers have now been balanced... But that's besides the point.

I've noticed there has been changes to the way ship size progression is done, and that there are multiple ways to progress your ship size.

What are those changes, and how can I upgrade my ship?
(Now that simply doing all outpost quests does absolutely nothing as they are made optional quests now...)

Comment: The content being from a nightly build does not make this about unreleased information.  Since the nightly builds are available for anyone who owns the game to opt-in to, that's publicly available, and we can happily support and answer.

Comment: This content has been moved to stable. Would you like the answer for that build?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, updated and answer away.

Comment: Also, if an answer is out of date, always post a new answer... Unless it's a minor change - Then in that case, edit the existing answer. (Or bug the author to change it)

Comment: I know you can buy them from the Penguin Bay located behind the outpost, but as of now I can't interact (e) with the shop even though it's highlighted. There must be some prerequisite that stops you from buying them first.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To upgrade your ship, you'll need [Upgrade Modules](http://starbounder.org/Upgrade_Module). The amount you need is 2, 4, 6, 8, then 10 respectively for each upgrade. These can be found in chests, reward bags, and rarely as monster drops.

You must then obtain a ship license. This can either be done by getting [Crew Members](http://starbounder.org/Crew) (2, 4, 6, 8, 10) for completing quests for settlers and hiring penguin mercenaries (after defeating Dreadwing), or alternatively by buying the license from The Penguin Bay at the outpost for increasing ([10,000](http://starbounder.org/Fake_Sparrow_License), [20,000](http://starbounder.org/Fake_Kestrel_License), [40,000](http://starbounder.org/Fake_Falcon_License), [80,000](http://starbounder.org/Fake_Eagle_License), [150,000](http://starbounder.org/Fake_Condor_License)) amounts of pixels:

[image: Buying a completely real license from The Penguin Bay]

Once you have the upgrade modules and the license (fake or real), you'll need to visit Penguin Pete at the outpost, who will carry out the upgrade:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This may not be entirely correct but I'm fairly certain once the crew size on board hits a certain quota you'll be granted the next license, you can also purchase fake licenses at the penguin bay shop next to the 2-Stop Teleshop

Answer (score -4):

You use commands: 
/spawnitem shipT1
/spawnitem shipT2
/spawnitem shipT3
/spawnitem shipT4
/spawnitem shipT5
/spawnitem shipT6
/spawnitem shipT7
/spawnitem shipT8
You need to make sure you are in your ship when you use it and that you use a capital 'T'

Comment: Did you not read the very first part of the question?